# Convert rectangle into rounded corner for all selected object in Powerpoint vba script

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to run a script in Powerpoint module to convert all selected rectangle shape into rounded shape, below are the script which I got online but its converting only the first selected rectangle

This for the powerpoint 2016

```
Sub SetShapeRoundingRadius()


    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim sngRadius As Single ' Radius size in points


    Set oShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    sngRadius = 0.1

    With oShape
       oShape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
        .Adjustments(1) = sngRadius
    End With

    Set oShape = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet will convert the selected objects. This version applies a loop to process all items returned by `Selection.ShapeRange`.

```
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim sngRadius As Single ' Radius size in points

sngRadius = 0.1
For Each oShape In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

    With oShape
         oShape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
        .Adjustments(1) = sngRadius
    End With
Next
Set oShape = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe Try this:**

```
Sub SetSdasdhapeRoundingRadius()


    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim sngRadius As Single ' Radius size in points

    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        shp.Select

            If InStr(1, shp.Name, "Rectangle") > 0 Then
            Set oShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
            sngRadius = 0.1

            With oShape
               oShape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle
                .Adjustments(1) = sngRadius
            End With

            Set oShape = Nothing
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

- If it works you can extend it to perform the same on All slide by looping.